# Random Array with min/max

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I need to create a two arrays. One with 24 random numbers between 5 and 20. The second with 24 random numbers between 1 and 10. I think I'm on the right track with creating the arrays but can't get the minimum of 5 & 1 to stick. Here's my code:

```
    function getRandomNumber(min, max)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

var volts = [];
var amps = [];


for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  volts.push(getRandomNumber(5, 20));
}

for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  amps.push(getRandomNumber(1, 10));
}

var power = 0;
for(var i=0; i < volts.length; i++){
  power = (volts[i]*amps[i]);
}

console.log(volts);
console.log(amps);
console.log(power);
```

How would I add a third loop that performs an equation of volts multiplied by amps? Each iteration would multiply the random elements produced by each array

Comment: arrays in javascript are zero based. the index is starting with zero.

Answer (score 1):

To get a min/max random number between 5 and 20, 
you'd use `Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 5`, from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
// Returns a random integer between min (include) and max (include)

Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

You can then use `Array.from` to create the array *smoothly*:

```js
function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

let volts = Array.from({length: 24}, () => randomBetween(5, 20));
let amps = Array.from({length: 24}, () => randomBetween(1, 10));

console.log(volts, amps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var volts = [];
var amps = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  volts.push(getRandomNumber(5, 20);
}

for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  amps.push(getRandomNumber(1, 10);
}

console.log(volts);
console.log(amps);
```

Also in case you would like to use ES6 you can try this code:

```
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const volts = Array.from({length: 24}, () => getRandomNumber(5, 20);
const amps = Array.from({length: 24}, () => getRandomNumber(1, 10);

console.log(volts);
console.log(amps);
```

UPDATE [06/09/2018]

If you need to multiply these two arrays you could just create a third loop:

```
result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  result.push(amps[i] * volts[i]);
} 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Any particular reason why I receive undefined?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `return` in `getRandomValues`.

Comment: Fixed @JustinHenehan

Comment: How would I add a third loop that performs an equation of volts multiplied by amps? Each iteration would multiply the random elements produced by each array. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandomArray(length, min, max){

    let arr = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arr.push((Math.random() * (max - min) + min).toFixed());;
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(getRandomArray(24, 5, 20));
```